# How do I make an instantiated object keep following my player after its instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I drew a little red animation thing for when my player gets hit. I have an arrow shooter in my level but my problem is the red damage effect instantiates where my player is at, but when my player moves the object stays in the player's old position. Like lets say my player is at x:10. The effect will spawn at x:10 but when I move to x:17 the effect will stay at x:10.

Here's my code

```
    public int damagedealt;
    public Player playerscript;
    public GameObject RedDamage;
    public Vector2 playerpos;
    public GameObject player;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerscript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        playerpos = player.transform.position;
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        
        
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerscript.health -= damagedealt;
            Instantiate(RedDamage, playerpos, transform.rotation);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
    }
```

and if it's useful at all here's the damage effect script

```
{
    public float duration;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        duration = .7f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        duration -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (duration <= .13f )
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add a follow script to the object you would like to follow your player or you can child the object to the player. When an object is childed to another, its transform becomes relative to its parent. In your case, your instantiated object would move relative to your player.

As this seems like a temporary effect that is repeated multiple times, it might make sense to child an empty object for the sole purpose of spawning your effect there. Create an empty gameObject that is childed (meaning placed under in the scene hierarchy) to your player object. Make sure to set the position of this new empty object in a place where you would like to spawn your object.

Once you are happy with where the object is placed, you can alter your `Instantiate` slightly to fit the new approach.[`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) has a few overloads to the method. The one I will use is as follows

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

Instead of specifying a rotation, position, etc, you will specify the parent at which the object will be placed and childed to. Here is what the script would now look like

```
public int damagedealt;
public Player playerscript;
public GameObject RedDamage;
public Vector2 playerpos;
public GameObject player;

// serializing a field will expose it in the editor even if marked private
// while not allowing other scripts to access it
[SerializeField] private Transform DisplayDamageFeedback = null;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerscript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playerpos = player.transform.position;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    
    
}
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        playerscript.health -= damagedealt;
        Instantiate(RedDamage, DisplayDamageFeedback);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
}
```

Make sure to assign the reference to `DamageFeedback` in the inspector to the empty gameObject you created earlier. If you need help on any of the steps just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

in the effects' 'Update' script:

```
GameObject  player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");;
public void MoveGameObject()
{
   transform.position = new Vector3(player.transfom.position.x,player.transform.position.y,player.transform.position.z);
}
```

This means that every Update, the player object is found, and the effect's position is set to match the players.

See the following link for Unity's example of position:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. Sorry this is a silly question but my effect is in the project/assets window in unity. I can't drag in stuff from the inspector to a prefab for some reason so I did what you said in the script, but for some reason it just doesn't find Player. I tried GameObject.Find and find with tag, it just doesn't set it to anything.

Comment: I would not grab the reference every frame. Using any sort of `Find` method in `Update()` can get costly. Store the reference in a `Start` or `Awake` method.

Comment: @John The most likely reason for this is that your object is not tagged as `Player`. The `FindGameObjectWithTag` will grab the first instance of an object that matches with the tag inside of the string(`""`) parameter.

Comment: @John could you post a image of what you Player object is called? Maybe lowercase?

Comment: What @TEEBQNE is very true as well, you should make one reference to 'player' in the Start() method instead

Comment: Yeah I don't know what the problem is. It's tagged and all, also I put it in start it just doesn't find anything. I think in other projects it worked so maybe it's a glitch?
This is my player name copied and pasted straight from unity: Player